# Java Uneven Multidimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I came by this piece of code and I'm not sure what is exactly happening. It's as follows:

```
       int twod [] [] = new int[4][];// i know the first one is row

       twod [0]  = new int[1];//
       twod [1]  = new int[2];//  What are these? 
       twod [2]  = new int[3];//
       twod [3]  = new int[4];//
```

What are the last 4 lines doing?

Comment: @pbabcdefp Well the code part is from the complete reference herbert schildt ninth edition. And yeah it does compile and has an output too in the program, i just need to know what this thing does.

Comment: @Dhananjay it *does not* compile. E.g on `twod [] [] = new int [1];` i get:
 - Syntax error, insert ". class" to complete Expression
 - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: @Turing85: I just remember something called as jagged array in c. Not similar but i guess i can allocate the remaining dimensions separately.

Comment: For your reference... http://www.java2s.com/Book/Java/0020__Language-Basics/Jagged_array.htm

Comment: got it thanks for the references guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you posted didn't compile for me.  I think this is what you want for jagged arrays.

```
   int twod [][] = new int[4][];// i know the first one is row

   twod[0] = new int[1];//
   twod[1] = new int[2];//  What are these? 
   twod[2] = new int[3];//
   twod[3] = new int[4];//
```

Results (In debug):

[image]

Comment: Yeah saw my mistake there. But its still not going in my head as to what is happening. Sorry i m a rookie

Comment: Simply put...  It's rows with different number of columns

Comment: So you mean its a way to actually modify the entire row, means if i want i can have the 2nd row with 10 columns and 3rd row with 5 columns, 4th row with 7 columns... So basically its on me to modify either rows or columns by my choice in any manner?

Comment: That is correct.  It all just depends on your use case of how jagged you want an array to be...  Another reference for study http://way2java.com/arrays/jagged-arrays-varying-column-size-arrays/

Comment: well thanks for the reference i got the entire stuff now.. No doubt remaining now , thanks..

Answer (score 4):

The above code does not compile. But I have a strong feeling OP meants something like this:

```
   int twod[][] = new int[4][];// i know the first one is row

   twod[0] = new int[1];
   twod[1] = new int[2];
   twod[2] = new int[3];
   twod[3] = new int[4];
```

This creates an array of the following shape (up->down = 1st dimension, left->right= 2nd dimension):

```
*
**
***
****
```

More specific, when we query the length of the arrays, we get these results:

```
twod.length -> 4
twod[0].length -> 1
twod[1].length -> 2
twod[2].length -> 3
twod[3].length -> 4
```

Comment: yeah exactly for the same purpose

Comment: This doesn't compile...  I'm using Netbeans

Comment: oh its kool i corrected mine syntax too above, apparently i use both netbeans and eclipse. but thats whats bothering me how does this work.

Comment: got it so this is to fix the length of the row